# Events which can be used during helm upgrade to be consumed in the docker image

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am very new to Helm and Kubernetes. I have a use case where, whenever there is a helm upgrade

```
helm upgrade xxx --values yy.yaml
```

I need to trigger invocation of a method in my docker image which is deployed onto the kubernetes pods ,so that i can work on the changes encountered in yy.yaml in the image code . Do we have some way of doing it ? Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem is not clear to me but i think, You can use helm hook to do the same thing. Please check [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/).
You can certainly use `pre-upgrade` hook to invoke your function.

Comment: @Taybur Rahaman , I have a method in my Image running on the kubernetes pod to be invoked when helm upgrade happens. Is it possible with helm hook. I could not find any examples.

Comment: @ Wytrzymały Wiktor , my use case is mentioned in the above comment. I dint find solution.

Comment: How do you invokes your method manuall? Is it like bash or python?

Comment: @Taybur Its a simple java method created in the image. As of now its a Scheduler in java running for every 30 seconds . But we want to someway to trigger only during helm upgrade.

Comment: then i will suggest to find out a way using bash command and that command will be executed during pre-upgrade hook.As you know, hooks create a job and that job will be be executed  by creating a container and you can execute any command in that container.